# Python - Convert HTML to csv

Tags: python, html, csv

I need to convert a number of html documents into csv format. Is there a module in python which I can use to do this without having to write custom code based on the html script? [This link](http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm), for example, does the job pretty well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) has support for reading HTML tables. See function [read_html](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.0/generated/pandas.read_html.html#pandas.read_html). You can output the read data with [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv) to a CSV file.

Comment: I had originally planned to convert to csv and process the data in R. But pandas seems like a powerful data tool in its own right. Thanks for this.